# TypeError for writer.writeheader() when writing CSV file

Tags: python, csv

#### Project

My project "edits" a row from a csv file ("bingus.csv") of which the username matches the variable "username". As a csv file can't be directly edited, my project does so by writing the content into a temporary file, editing that and writing it back to the csv.
Content:

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

filename = "bingus.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
fieldnames = ['username', 'fullname', 'age', 'stutter', 'speed']

fullname = input("Your full name : ")
username = input("Your username  : ")
with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    filename = ['username', 'fullname', 'age', 'gender', 'stutter', 'speed']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow({
            "username": row["username"],
            "fullname": fullname if row["username"] == username else row["fullname"],
            "age": row["age"],
            "stutter": row["stutter"],
            "speed": row["speed"],
        })
    shutil.move(temp_file, filename)
```

#### CSV

"bingus.csv"
Content:

```
username,fullname,age,gender,stutter,speed
annab,Anna Burr,15,f,y,f
tim1,Timothy Mayers,18,m,n,s
```

#### Problem

While writer.writeheader() has empty brackets, it seems to expect a byte-like object and is trying to relay a string? The reason for that is a complete mistery to me and I couldn't find anything online, this usually worked when I used it in different projects. Is there something I'm missing or understanding wrong? Is the mistake in a different line and the error is shown for this line for a different reason?
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\Project\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    writer.writeheader()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\csv.py", line 143, in writeheader
    return self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tempfile.py", line 474, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: remove the 'b' flag from ```with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile, temp_file:```

Comment: Please, share your actual code. This snippet will raise `NameError` because `fieldnames` is not defined.

Comment: @buran sorry should be fixed now

Comment: @AbbeGijly tried to do so and failed

Comment: can you print the exception you're getting?  is it still ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```?   Also, note the typo ```writer.writheader()``` should be ```writer.writeheader()``` (missing an 'e')

Comment: @AbbeGijly it is absolutely the same
and i thought im pretty sure i fixed that typo before, also didnt work without it